# MismatchSenderId when sending GCM messages to an Android App

Tags: python, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send GCM messages with a python application to an android APP. I execute the application in the emulator, and the gcm messages are received. Afterwards, I debug the Android application with eclipse studio in the movil device (Android 4.4.4). When I send messages I obtained the following error:

```
{"multicast_id":***********,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":
    [{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

The python code in the script:

```
from gcm import GCM

gcm = GCM('AIzaSyC8qws************************')
data = {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'}

# JSON request
reg_ids = ['f8GR1GrUB1w:AP*******************************']
response = gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data)

# Extra arguments
res = gcm.json_request(
    registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data,
    collapse_key='uptoyou', delay_while_idle=True, time_to_live=3600
)
```

I have checked that `reg_ids` vector has the api-key that the Android application requests to the gcm server.  What is the problem, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`MismatchSenderID` is one of the error responses discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#error-codes).

Basically it's an issue when you register your client app with a Sender ID (aka Project Number) that is not the project that has the API key ("AIza...") referenced in your code.